# istio: VirtualService url rewriting or forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, istio

I have an Istio VirtualService with a match and a route and redirect url defined as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-pro
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /events
    route:
    - destination:
        host: event-service
        port:
          number: 8000
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /blog
    redirect:
      uri: /
      authority: blog.mydomain.com
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: default-service
        port:
          number: 8000
```

this VirtualService work as follows:

1. if the request is **[www.mydomain.com/events](http://www.mydomain.com/events)** it will forward to **event-service**.
2. if the request is **[www.mydomain.com/blog](http://www.mydomain.com/blog)** it will redirect host to **blog.mydomain.com**.
3. if the request is **[www.mydomain.com/anyother](http://www.mydomain.com/anyother)** it will forward to **default-service**.

In case no.2 I am redirecting **[www.mydomain.com/blog](http://www.mydomain.com/blog)** to **blog.mydomain.com** page because my blog page is hosted on that domain.

now my problem is while redirecting the URL, the browser URL is changing to **blog.mydomain.com**. I want it to remain the same **[www.mydomain.com/blog](http://www.mydomain.com/blog)** but the content of **blog.mydomain.com** should be display on the screen.

Comment: I wonder if Kubernetes [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) Service and [Service Entry](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) may be what you need ?

Comment: so, basically you want to go to `hello.com`, but you want your web server yo serve whatever is under `hello.com/something`?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but acutely what I want is I want the content of hey.com in hello.com/something without a change in a web browser URL it still should remain hello.com/something with the content of hey.com.

Answer (score 2):

```
- match:
 - uri:
    prefix: /blog
 name: blog.mydomain.com
 rewrite:
   authority: blog.mydomain.com
   uri: /blog
 route:
 - destination:
    host: blog.mydomain.com
```

Add the above rule in the virtual service, then create this service entry.

```html
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: blog
spec:
  hosts:
  - blog.mydomain.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: DNS
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **rewrite** with a destination : https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRewrite

If the destination is external to the Service Mesh, you'll also need a ServiceEntry

Comment: By using this URL on the browser will change to blog.mydomain.com. I want it to remain the same www.mydomain.com/blog.